# JavaScript Import / export fail

Tags: javascript, html

I made a little script to just highlight for myself some words automatically because I am useing  Html format to write personal notes.

It works if I let everything in the same file but it's impossible to understand how to import and export works; I even downloaded a sample package from [here](https://github.com/mdn/js-examples) and it doesn't work either.

I know there is big packaging existing to do the same thing but I just want to push a simple "js" file in the same folder and let it do the work, I just need to import/export to don't have to rewrite each time I modify the common ".js" (for coloring).

Perhaps I don't use the good keyword, but I don't find any correct information.

I will let a basic sample of my code (for the while they are in the same folder)

```js
//csharp.js
import "./ColorText.js"


function foo(){
    const blueWords = ["Task", "TaskScheduler", "void"];
    var xx = document.getElementsByClassName("csharp");
    for (i=0;i<xx.length;i++){
        var str=xx[i].innerHTML;
        ColorTextInBlue(xx[i], "Task");
    }
}
```

I tried this part even with "//target..." to disable it.

```js
export{ColorTextInBlue};

function ColorTextInBlue(target, str)
{
    
    target.innerHTML=target.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(str, 'g'),
        "<font color=\"#0000FF\">"+str+"</font>");
}
```

HTML part

```
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="module" src="./ColorText.js" ></script>
    <script src="./CSharp.js" ></script>
```

I read there is something about a javascript revision but it's not clear at all.

If possible modify directly the code to see how it must be done.

---

Code edited to remove the dot, the second loop and to simplify the code.

Comment: `ColorTextInBlue` and `ColorText.InBlue` are not the same. `ColorText` isn’t defined anywhere. “It doesn’t work” isn’t a useful description of the problem; have you checked the developer tools? Are you using the `module` attribute on the `<script>`?

Comment: Thanks to Nitin for the corrections, i must remove the second loop i didn't realize it was an error. And i just swa ColorTextInBlue got a dot by error (thanks to Sebastian Simon)

Comment: A couple of other things: 1) Declare your loop variables properly (and you should start using `const` and `let` these days instead of `var`). 2) JavaScript functions tend to be in camelcase: `colorTextInBlue`. 3) If `colorTextInBlue` is the only function in the file you can use `export default colorTextInBlue`, and then `import colorTextInBlue from ...`  - no curly braces.

Comment: sadly it doesn't work :/ but thanks .